# PHP : add write permission to file after move_uploaded_file()

Tags: php, file-upload, chmod

After an image is uploaded with PHP, I want to make the image file writable in order to add a watermark to it . Here are the codes I used:

```
if(isset($_FILES['file_poster']['tmp_name']) && $_FILES['file_poster']['tmp_name'] != '') {
        $random_filename = substr(md5(time()), 0, 9);
        $ext = '.jpg';
        if(strpos(strtolower($_FILES['file_poster']['name']), '.png') > -1) {
            $ext = '.png';
        }

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_poster']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' .  $random_filename . $ext);
        chmod(ABS_PATH . $random_filename, 0666);
        $random_filename = 'uploads/' .  $random_filename . $ext;

        // add watermark codes omitted
}
```

After the file is uploaded, the file permission becomes **644**. Then I tried to use `chmod()` to change it to writable ( **666** ), but the permission doesn't change.

The `/uploads` folder has permission **777**. Is there any reason that makes `chmod()` function fails to change permission? or is there a workaround?

Note: PHP 5 is used. GD is working properly.

Comment: What is `ABSPATH`? My guess is `ABSPATH` and the relative `uploads` directory are pointing at different locations

Comment: `ABS_PATH` is the absolute path prefix of the folder , e.g. `/var/www/`. The absolute path & relative path are pointing to same folder, as upload is successful

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looks like you need to swap your last two lines, eg

```
$random_filename = 'uploads/' .  $random_filename . $ext;
chmod(ABS_PATH . $random_filename, 0666);
```

Be very careful when using relative paths such as `'uploads/' . $random_filename . $ext`. If the working file is included into another file, the current directory may differ.

I would recommend something like this

```
$destFile = __DIR__ . '/uploads/' . $random_filename . $ext;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_poster']['tmp_name'], $destFile);
chmod($destFile, 0666);
```

where the magic `__DIR__` constant always contains the absolute path to the parent directory of the file you're actually in.