# Save file in /var/www from html upload file

Tags: php, html, linux, apache

I have an issue in a program that uploads files from html in my local server, into the `/var/www/html/my_app` directory.

In this directory I have changed the permission with:

`sudo chmod -R 777`

So I can save the photo that uploads in the directory inside my_app.

But here is the problem, when I upload a file inside the directory it always has the `read` permission.

Can I change that? So all the files I upload have permission.

```
chmod 777
```

Comment: Why would you give 777 permissions to a `/www/` directory though?

Comment: This previous question might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15262748/php-add-write-permission-to-file-after-move-uploaded-file

Comment: @AndrewLyndem i make the 777 permission for the file and the directories in.

Answer (score 0):

move_uploaded-file always set permission to 600 for any uploaded file whatever configuration set in apache umask. you can use chmod in context with your code while uploading file and set permission.

chmod($target_path, 0664);

http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php In the comment section another users have same issue so they are describing same thing.